# Keep the contents of the Vector intact

Tags: java, servlets

From my website this servlet below gets called number of times and every time it has to store a value in vector. But I dont want the vector to lose its previous contents once the servlet execution is complete. Like a shopping cart.

```
public void putValues(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  throws ServletException, IOException
 {
Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<Object>();
 vector.add(request.getParameter("UID"));
 }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't create a new Vector everytime the method is called, use a instance variable.

```
private Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<Object>();    

public void putValues(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  throws ServletException, IOException
     {
     vector.add(request.getParameter("UID"));
     }
```

Comment: So every time putValues gets called wont it refresh the contents of the object vector.. I mean wont it get new memory allocated?

Comment: everytime you call `vector.add(something)` something will be added to the already existent vector, and everything that previously was in the vector will stay there.

Comment: But every time servlet is called that servlet's new instance is created and memory is allocated to its declared variables. Old vector contents wont be accessible.

Comment: look at @PawelSolarski answer.

Comment: The answer is good, however, I suggest storing stuff in the HttpSession object.

Comment: @jlordo But i dont want to use session. I saw his answer and that would defntly work.

Answer (score 1):

A new `Vector` instance is created on every call of the method.

Situations like this are usually handled by keeping such objects in the `HttpSession` object.

I would also suggest you use `ArrayList` instead of Vector or `Collections.synchronizedList()` if you really need a synchronized version of a `List`.

Comment: look at the answer above. Is is correct?? I mean wil that work?

Comment: Why ArrayList or Collections.synchronizedList(). Just asking out of curiosity?

Comment: Vector is an older synchronized API. Use the newer ones instead. Read about differences between Vector and ArrayList in javadocs and on the web.

Comment: You're welcome. Note my updated answer. I was previously wrong with multiple instances. It is actually that on every servlet request, a new Thread is created, but it is handled by just one single instance of the servlet.

Comment: So if I use the Vector the way Jlordo has written it will work right?

Answer (score 1):

You should obviously use HttpSession.

```
doXXX(...){
    Object data = request.getSession().getAttribute("data");
    if(data==null){
       request.getSession().setAttribute("data", new Vector());
    }
```

Then, each time servlet is called, use:

```
((Vector)(request.getSession().getAttribute("data"))).add(request.getParameter("UID"))
```

Comment: I thot of this but i thot may be there was an other way. Would've been great if cud've implemented using different method.

Comment: This is the preferred way, as http sessions are to store the conversation state, and this is what you try to achieve

Answer (score 0):

You can Store the Vector the Contents on a temp text file